# Markdown with Syntax highlighting in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to implement the same stack overflow text-area with syntax highlighting in Python and have come this far but i am not able to get it working.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import preview

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        markdown_content = request.args.get['wdd-input']
        post_preview = preview.markdown(markdown_content['data'])
        return render_template('test.html', result=post_preview)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('demo.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

preview is something which does syntax highlighting and its based upon Pygments.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PageDown Demo Page</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/highlighting.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/demo.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/hycus-textarea.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function (m) {
      m(document).ready(function () {
        m('textarea.wmd-input').TextAreaResizer();
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div id="pagedwon">
        <div id="tabnav">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="markdown_tab" style="padding: 0 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <li class="active"><a href="#edit" data-toggle="tab">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#markdownpreview" data-toggle="tab">Preview</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="edit">
            <div class="wmd-panel">
              <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" rows="10" name="text-input">
This is the *pagedown* editor.
------------------------------

**Note**: Just plain **Markdown**, except that the input is sanitized: **HTML** is not allowed.
</textarea>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              (function () {
                  var pagedown_editor = new Markdown.Editor();
                  pagedown_editor.run();
              })();
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
              (function (m) {
                m("#markdown_tab a").click(function () {
                  if (m(this).html() == "Preview"){
                    var markdown_content = m("#wmd-input").val();
                    if (!markdown_content) {
                      m("div#markdownpreview").html("Empty Markdown Content.");
                    } else {
                      content_to_preview = {
                        "data": markdown_content
                      }
                      m.post("/", content_to_preview)
                        .success( function(preview_content){
                          if (preview_content == 'None'){
                            m("div#markdownpreview").html("No content received.");
                          } else {
                            m("div#markdownpreview").html(preview_content);
                          }
                        })
                        .error( function () {
                          m("div#markdownpreview").html("Sorry, error occurred. Please retry.");
                        });
                    }
                  }
                });
              })(jQuery);
            </script>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-pane markdown-body" id="markdownpreview">
            Loding preview content ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is log from the console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2014 20:25:01] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

How to get it working, please help. I am new to Flask.

Comment: Try running the program with debug mode turned on, that will give you a more insightful error message then just the 500 Server Error message you're getting.  Change your `app.run()` to `app.run(debug=True)` to activate the debug console.  Then let us know that information that's shown in the stacktrace you'll get.

Comment: Nope, dint get an error.

Comment: What shows up in the browser?

Comment: the browser shows the editor and when the tab of preview is clicked, Sorry, error occurred. Please retry. is shown.

Comment: Okay, so the error isn't from the browser, it's just from the Javascript you're running, it's calling a view, failing, and displaying that message.  I think that's because you're only posting `data` to the view, but the view is looking for `wdd-input`, and when that doesn't exist, then the call to preview fails, generates an error, and the js then in turn shows that canned message

Answer (score 3):

- First, [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.args) is for query string parameters, but you are sending over data via `POST`.  You should be using [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.form) instead.
- Second, [`MultiDict.get`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.get) is a function, and does not support the [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.%5F%5Fgetitem%5F%5F) protocol (which is the cause of your 500 error).
- Third, as @Doobeh points out in the comments, you are sending the data over under the key `data`, but you are trying to access it via the key "wdd-input" - this will result in a [`BadRequest`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest) error.
- Finally, the value extracted from [`request.form`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.form) will be a string (which does not support strings as [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.%5F%5Fgetitem%5F%5F) values) - and you don't need it anyway, as you already have the entire string.

A re-worked version of your `POST` portion:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    markdown_content = request.form.get('data', 'No content yet ...')
    post_preview = preview.markdown(markdown_content)
    return render_template('test.html', result=post_preview)
```